# SQL update using LAG

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am trying to update a table that looks like below. I want the colB to be updated with 1 until we get to 3(12-10-2020)..then update colB with 3 until 12-15-2020. I am trying to use Lag and merge but cant get to udpate all at one. Have to run the query many time. Any clues here?? Please help. Thank you so much!

```
ColA         ColB     ColC         
12-1-2020    1         X  
12-2-2020    0
12-3-2020    0
12-4-2020    0
.
.
.12-10-2020  3         Y
.

.
12-15-2020    0
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the data that you want using `lag(ignore nulls)`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(case when colc is not null then colb end ignore nulls) over (order by cola)
from t;
```

Not all databases support this standard construct.  But you can use:

```
select t.*, max(colb) over (partition by grp)
       lag(case when colc is not null then colb end ignore nulls) over (order by cola)
from (select t.*, 
             count(colc) over (order by cola) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```

How this is incorporated into an `update` depends on the database, but you can readily calculate the value on the fly.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I am using SQL DB. Am not sure but the SQL doesn't seem to be working for me.  "count(colc) over (order by cola) as grp" is giving me random answers

Comment: I am trying to do this :      with cte_max as (
select  [fid], CDate,Ptype, max( case when (Pcount is not NULL )
then (Pcount end) 
over (partition by [fid], CDate,Ptype, order by  [fid], CDate,Ptype, ) cummcnt
from ct

)
select * from cte_max order by  [fid], CDate,Ptype

Comment: Trying to see if Merge can update in one shot using the above SQL queries

Comment: @SA2020 . . . I don't know what "random answers" means.  There is nothing random about the expression.  You should tag with the database you are using.  Providing a db/SQL fiddle would also be helpful.